# Minimization of piecewise real multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

I want to minimize a multivariable function with the following form:
$$
f(\vec{x}) = g(\vec{x}) + | h (\vec{x}) | ,
$$
this is a piecewise function depending on the sign of $h (\vec{x})$, and I assume that these three functions are all differentiable.
For the moment I don't think it's too relevant but I also know that this function is convex.

When $h (\vec{x}) \neq 0$ it should be enough to look for the gradient of the two pieces:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial {\vec{x}} } \left( g(\vec{x}) + h(\vec{x}) \right)  = 0 \quad \text{if} \quad h(\vec{x}) > 0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial {\vec{x}} } \left( g(\vec{x}) - h(\vec{x}) \right)  = 0 \quad \text{if} \quad  h(\vec{x}) < 0
$$

But what about the surface $\mathcal{Y} = \left\{ \vec{y} \;\; \text{s.t.} \;\; h(\vec{y})=0 \right\} $?

Is studying the gradient of the first term restricted on this surface enough?
I mean:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial {\vec{y}} } g(\vec{y}) = 0 \quad \text{with} \quad h(\vec{y}) = 0
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimization of $g$ restricted to the surface $h=0$ can be done using a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I know that, but does your answer mean that such a procedure is correct?
I.e. if the minimum exists will it be the solution of one of the three minimizations?

Comment: If a minimum exists, it will be in one of the three sets $\{y: h(y) < 0\}$, $\{y: h(y) = 0\}$ $\{y: h(y) > 0\}$, and it will minimize the restriction of the function to that set.
Of course it doesn't go the other way: a minimum of the function restricted to $\{y: h(y) = 0\}$ might not even be a local minimum of the unrestricted function.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is just what I imagined.
But I was a bit confused by the fact that I could not find this statement expressed clearly, since most of the stuff that I have found on similar topics introduces subgradients!